# javascript onload function scope interrogation

Tags: javascript, iteration, onload, htmlcollection

I'm trying to code a function in javascript that will automatically add a button into some components that are from particular class.

I've finally succeeded by writing the following code :

```
<html>
    <head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        window.onload=function populateEditContainer(){
        //function populateEditContainer(){
            console.log("fonction");
            var editContainers = document.getElementsByClassName("editContainer");
            console.log("collection");
            console.log(editContainers);
            console.log("taille");
            console.log(editContainers.length);
            console.log(editContainers);
            for(var i=0, editContainer; editContainer = editContainers[i]; i++){
                console.log("boucle");
                console.log(editContainer);
                var form = document.createElement("form");
                    console.log(form);
                form.setAttribute('method',"post");
                    console.log(form);
                var button = document.createElement("input");
                    console.log("trace");
                button.setAttribute('type',"button");
                button.setAttribute('value',"editer");
                    console.log(button);
                form.appendChild(button);
                editContainer.appendChild(form);
            }
        }
        console.log("code");
        //window.onload=populateEditContainer();
    </script>
    <title>Configurations</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>
        Configuration manager ! 
    </h1>

    <P>Current configuration</P>
    <div style="width:33%">
        <table style="width:100%">
            <tr>
                <td>header reference label</td>
                <td></td>
                <td class="editContainer" />
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>highlight color</td>
                <td></td>
                <td class="editContainer" />
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>account number</td>
                <td></td>
                <td class="editContainer" />
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</body>
```

But, before this, i've encountered one issue that i'm not able to understand.

The issue : the HTMLCollection.length keep zero as value, but the collection seems to be correctly populated in the debug view, so the loop is not executed at all.

```
<html>
    <head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        //window.onload=function populateEditContainer(){
        function populateEditContainer(){
            console.log("fonction");
            var editContainers = document.getElementsByClassName("editContainer");
            console.log("collection");
            console.log(editContainers);
            console.log("taille");
            console.log(editContainers.length);
            console.log(editContainers);
            for(var i=0, editContainer; editContainer = editContainers[i]; i++){
                console.log("boucle");
                console.log(editContainer);
                var form = document.createElement("form");
                    console.log(form);
                form.setAttribute('method',"post");
                    console.log(form);
                var button = document.createElement("input");
                    console.log("trace");
                button.setAttribute('type',"button");
                button.setAttribute('value',"editer");
                    console.log(button);
                form.appendChild(button);
                editContainer.appendChild(form);
            }
        }
        console.log("code");
        window.onload=populateEditContainer();
    </script>
    <title>Configurations</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>
        Configuration manager ! 
    </h1>
    <P>Current configuration</P>
    <div style="width:33%">
        <table style="width:100%">
            <tr>
                <td>header reference label</td>
                <td></td>
                <td class="editContainer" />
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>highlight color</td>
                <td></td>
                <td class="editContainer" />
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>account number</td>
                <td></td>
                <td class="editContainer" />
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</body>
```

Is it possible to have an explanation about this ?

Answer (score 0):

You've got a typo:

```
window.onload=populateEditContainer();
```

This line is *actually executing your function*, synchronously.

You just want to pass a reference to execute later, on-load:

```
window.onload=populateEditContainer;
```

The reason it works in the top example is that you're defining and passing the function, but not executing it.